# IOS app doesn't show up in Firebase Analytics

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, google-analytics

I build a firebase iOS app. It works with Firestore and it works fine but the problem is the app doesn't show up when I click on dashboard (under analytics in the Firebase console). I have reinstalled firebase (multible times) and I have checked if analytics was enabled and it was. Does anyone know what I need to check or something?

I followed the instructions from firebase when adding firebase to the IOS project (if this was installed correctly firestore wouldn't work). The only difference that I didn't use cocoapods but Swift package dependencies. I followeded this instructions: https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/swift-package-manager. The reason that I didn't use cocoapods is that I just can't get accesses to the iOS project. It keeps giving me zsh: permission denied. I have tried everything from chmod 777 to using sudo. I gave the terminal full disk acces but I keep getting permission denied. Anyway that's why I use swift package manager. I use the following dependencies:

- FirebaseAnalytics
- FirebaseFirestore
- FirebaseCrashlytics

Everything works fine apart from getting user data on the dashboard. Does anyone know what this problem could be? I don't know what code to give. I do use FirebaseApp.configure() in AppDelegate (otherwise Firestore wouldn't) work. But I do get this error in the logs:

```
app[74317:4168079] [] nw_protocol_get_quic_image_block_invoke dlopen libquic failed
```

Because of confusion in the comment section this edit.
Firebase gives you automatically all kinds of information on the analytics page about your app. When enabled the only thing you need to do (according to the docs) is call FirebaseApp.configure() in AppDelegate. I have done this and it works because otherwise Firestore would not work. But the IOS app doesn't show up on the analytics page. I have reinstalled Firebase 6 times on my IOS app and still nothing. Does anyone know what could possible go wrong? Because this should all work automatically so I don't know what code to post.

Comment: Which stats are you trying to read?  And what have you to done in your app for them?

Comment: If I use the app on a android device then the analytics dashboard show me that I had 1 active users on the Firebase Dashboard along with a lot of other information such as platform breakdown, app release versions etc.

Comment: Again, which stats are you trying to read?  Again, what have you to done in your app for them?

Comment: Im not trying to read anything. But normally when Firebase is installed you can see al sorts of informatie (see previous). But now the IOS app is not even showing up under platform breakdown. That why my question is called IOS app doesn't show up in Firebase analytics. I need platform breakdown etc information in the future.

Comment: I have waited for over 3 months.

Comment: I have nothing more to tell you unless you tell us what statistics you are trying to get with Firebase Analytics and what you have done in YOUR APP, not in Firebase Console, to get them.

Comment: Do you know how Firebase works? Because when you install Firebase you should automatically get analytics data (when enabled, which ofc I have). The android version of the app already shows me al kinds of data. The IOS versions shows me nothing. The IOS versions doesn't even show up... Again this should work all automatically. The only thing I need to do is call FirebaseApp.configure() which I have done. Thats the strange thing... So again, apart from that I have done nothing in my app to get analytics data. Because this should go automatically. I reinstalled Firebase 6times so hence this topic

Comment: Did you do https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/swift-package-manager#analytics

Comment: Thank you I added that and now I see active users!

Answer (score 6):

I forgot to add -ObjC to my build settings. That fixed my problem.
Link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/swift-package-manager#analytics